# R - Shiny : Colors of Layout

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I want whole layout to be of color `#84754C`. But some portion is blue. How can I make that portion also of color `#84754C`? Can anyone help?

**Code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(HTML("

                    .box.box-solid.box-primary>.box-header {
                    color:#fff;
                    background:#84754C
                    }
                    .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                    background-color: #84754C;
                    }


                    ")),

    fluidRow(
      box(width = 6, title = "test", status = "primary", solidHeader = 
            TRUE,
          "Box content"
      )
    )
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify the element that you want to change the colour of. `.skin-blue .main-header .logo` only refers to the portion that changed colour, not the whole top bar. Change the code to:

```
tags$style(HTML("

                .box.box-solid.box-primary>.box-header {
                color:#fff;
                background:#84754C
                }
                .skin-blue .main-header .logo {
                background-color: #84754C;
                }
                .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                background-color: #84754C;
                }

                "))
```